# How do you export configuration from configuration module

Tags: configuration

I need to include the configuration that I track in configuration modules into my install profile or however I will allow so that it will be initialised on install. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable **Configuration Management UI** submodule

Goto yoursite.com/admin/config/system/configuration/migrate

There is links for `Export` & `Import`

[image]